# How to convert a SAS-date to a R-date (or SAS-datetime to R-datetime)

Tags: r, date, sas

Does anyone know, how to convert a sas-date (01JAN1990) to a r-date (or a sas datetime to a r datetime?)

```
df <- data.frame(date1 = c("01JAN1990", "02AUG2010"), date2=c("24DEC2016:11:60:60","25DEC2017:12:00:00"))
df$date1 <- as.character(df$date1)
df$date2 <- as.character(df$date2)
df
```

Can I use `as.Date(df$date1, "%d%m%Y")` with another value for m?

---

Edit: And why can't I slice the date part of the datetime-variable `date2` and apply %d%B%Y?

```
df <- data.frame(date1 = c("01JAN1990", "02AUG2010"), date2=c("24DEC2016:11:60:60","25DEC2017:12:00:00"))
df$date1 <- as.character(df$date1)
df$date2 <- as.character(df$date2)
df %>% mutate(date3 = substr(date2, 1, 9),
              date4 = as.Date(date3, "%d%B%Y")) %>% glimpse()
```

Which gives me NA-Values (`date4`)

Comment: Use `as.Date(df$date1, "%d%B%Y")` See `?strptime` for all the formatting `%` codes.

Answer (score 0):

If you still are getting `NA`s, here is a work around

```r
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(date1 = c("01JAN1990", "02AUG2010"), date2=c("24DEC2016:11:60:60","25DEC2017:12:00:00"))
df$date1 <- as.character(df$date1)
df$date2 <- as.character(df$date2)
#Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")

df %>% mutate(date3 = substr(date2, 1, 9),
              date4 = format(dmy(date3), "%d%^b%Y")) %>% glimpse()
#Output 
# Observations: 2
# Variables: 4
# $ date1 <chr> "01JAN1990", "02AUG2010"
# $ date2 <chr> "24DEC2016:11:60:60", "25DEC2017:12:00:00"
# $ date3 <chr> "24DEC2016", "25DEC2017"
# $ date4 <chr> "24DEC2016", "25DEC2017"
```

Hope that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks again! I found out that the problem was a language problem, wich I could solve by using `sys.setlocale()`. The months are spelled slightly different in German. Because of that in certain cases the date conversion failed.